# Events using React Js

Tags: reactjs

```html
<body>
  <button id="btnId">Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

I have this html code above and I want to add a click event on the button with the id "btnId" using react js...how will i do that without updating that button...

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by *dynamically*?

Comment: by using class ex. class Sample extends React.Component{render(){ return(<button onClick={this.someFunction}>Click</button>)}}

Comment: Please EDIT your question and add more details to it instead of posting comments to your own question. Thanks

Comment: @KreeshianAlvirGutierrez you can use `addEventListener` just like in vanilla javascript inside `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: @Chris I got it, thank you for the answer I thought that componentDidMount() was used for making api calls.

Comment: @KreeshianAlvirGutierrez `cDM` can be used for *anything* after the component has finished mounting to the DOM - not *just* API calls :)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind events in 2 ways

**1.** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51474887/4270123

**2.** Here is the example

```
class Button extends React.Component {

 handleClick(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(e.target.id);
   alert("#" + e.target.id + " is clicked"); 
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <button onClick={ (e) => this.handleClick(e) } id="btnId">
       Click Me!
     </button>
   );    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code might give you an idea.

```
class Button  extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleClick.bind(this);
 }

 handleClick(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("I am clicked"); 
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
       Click Me!
     </button>
   );    
  }
}
```